# Why it is oscillating? is this self oscillation? how to remove

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, resonance, oscillation

Hello i have an circuit (2 stage op amplifier) with an resonance coil on input. I give an impulse on the coil and the circuit start resonating at frequency 1khz for seconds.

1. How i can change the circuit to stop self-oscillations?
2. Is this op amp self-oscillation?

image 1 - circuit
[image: my circuit]

image 2 - signal
[image: signal]

image 3 - Spectrum
[image: spectrum]

image 4 - board

[image: board]

image 5 - other side

[image]

image 6 - battery

[image]

Comment: That's definitely *something* oscillating. If the TL071s are being overdriven it could be a subharmonic of your tank frequency (which is 6.325 kHz), or it could be oscillations from parasitic elements. Show us your board layout; there may be too much parasitic capacitance at one of the output nodes.

Comment: Does the TL071 recommend any bypass capacitors be installed on their power pins?

Comment: added board image, there is no parasitic elements on board, only this these from circuit

Comment: @ViacheslavPopika There are definitely parasitic elements on the board. The *definition* of a parasitic element is an element that's there unintentionally, because wires have finite resistance, two conductors near each other have capacitance, etc. Like rdtsc says, you don't have any bypass capacitors; that could be the problem. Show us the other side of the board, too.

Comment: added other side and battery

Comment: it is oscillating on 1k what is the input coil and capacitor LC frequency. Maybe some power from input can go thru the op amp?

Comment: You are attempting to get a gain of more than 40,000 (200*200), so the circuit will be highly sensitive to noise. Your schematic shows +/- 5 V supplies, which probably consist of two 3.7 V batteries in series, plus a voltage regulator (not shown), for each. There should be fairly large capacitors on the board for the power rails, as well as smaller bypass capacitors near the op-amps. And good design practice would add 1k resistors in series with the non-inverting inputs to balance impedance.

Answer (score 3):

That may be self oscillation, but I don't think so. I think your second op-amp is saturated. That output may be just noise (closed-loop gain is huge), or it may be the op-amps' best attempt at amplification with a saturated second stage. Probably a bit of both.

I refer to this [TL071 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074h.pdf).

You have ±3.7V supplies, not ±5V as in your schematic. This limits your output to about ±2V. See page 17, under "maximum peak output voltage swing".

With a combined gain of nearly 50,000 only 60μV of input will cause the second op-amp to saturate. In fact, since these devices have input offset voltage of 2mV, typically (page 17, "input offset voltage"), it is all but guaranteed that the output of the second op-amp is already saturated one way or the other.

For this reason, I don't trust your graph of output, showing it to be centered around 0V. How did you obtain this data, and plot that graph?

With such high gain, you will not be able to directly couple the two stages, you'll have to AC couple them (see C1 and R5 below), to remove any DC offset from the first stage. Even then, the output of the second stage will likely be significantly offset from zero volts, but the op-amps will probably not be saturated:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5FeHI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It will only take about \$\pm \frac{3V}{50000}=\pm 60\mu V\$ at the input to cause the output to swing as close as it can to the positive/negative supply rail. If this circuit is successfully amplifying, just be aware that any input over 60μV amplitude will cause output clipping. For example, with a 1mV amplitude sinusoidal input, the output will look more like a square wave of amplitude 2V or so.

Also, as detailed in the datasheet on page 17, under "Common-mode voltage range", with supplies of ±3.7V, the input may not fall below -0.7V, or rise above +3.7V. If that happens, the op-amp makes no guarantees about what happens at the output.

For all the above reasons, the TL07x range of op-amps is a terrible choice for such a low voltage supply. Look for "rail-to-rail" input and output op-amps, that work with a 5V supply, such as the [TLC2271](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2272.pdf).